# About ending conversation in SEAM 2.1.2

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I have a question about seam 2.1.2

I want to end a conversation when the user click in menu, but this must be done in menu.xhtml or pages.xml. I need this because i have the following problem:

1. click page 'A' in menu
2. click in "search" button to show the list A.
3. forget about list 'A' and click in page 'B' in menu.
4. click in "search" button to show the list B.
5. do the step 1 again and the list 'A' continue there even i do not click in "search" button.

If i want to use @End i would need to create a new method just for start the page. I tryed the  tag in pages.xml and propagation=end in menu, but the list still been showing the results before i click in the button

The menu button:

```
<li><s:link propagation="none" action="/T925Historico.seam" value="Historico 925" /></li>
```

Pages.xml

```
<page view-id="/T925Historico.xhtml" login-required="true" action="#{usuarioBean.validaUsuario()}">
        <navigation>
            <rule if-outcome="erro">
                <redirect view-id="/error.xhtml"/>
            </rule>
            <rule if-outcome="detalhe">
                <redirect view-id="/T925Retorno.xhtml" include-page-params="true" />
            </rule>
            <end-conversation/>
        </navigation>
    </page>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`<end-conversation/>` should be inside each `<rule>`, so try...

```
<page view-id="/T925Historico.xhtml" login-required="true" action="#{usuarioBean.validaUsuario()}">
   <navigation>
      <rule if-outcome="erro">
         <redirect view-id="/error.xhtml"/>
         <end-conversation/>
      </rule>
      <rule if-outcome="detalhe">
         <redirect view-id="/T925Retorno.xhtml" include-page-params="true" />
         <end-conversation/>
      </rule>
   </navigation>
</page>
```